# Thread checkChange of Textfield

Tags: java, multithreading, textfield

I try to react to inputs of two Textfields and depending on whats typed in them I enable or disable some buttons

The Code snippet below should do this but the Problem is it doesn't work every time I start the Programm.
Sometimes it works (the buttons get enabled and disabled correct) sometimes it does nothing if I type the same input in the textfields.
In practice its about to insert a Port and an IP.
depending on the input there should be buttons setDisable or setEnable

I watched same Tutorials about Threading to look out if my basic Thread construction is correct. I couldn´t find my mistake or a hint of my mistake so if someone could give me a hint why my programm react like this I would be grateful

I have not work to much with Threading and I start my program in eclipse if this information are useful.

Code snippet:

```
    public static void threadSettings(String args[]) {
        Task<Void> checkChangeSettings = new Task<Void>() {
            // MinZeichen da minimale Ip bei Ipv6 0::1
            // Annahe kann falsch sein
            int minZeichenIP = 2;
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                while(true) {
                // If the input of the ip and port are done enable 
                // the Button Client
                    if((txtIPEingabe.getLength() >= minZeichenIP) && 
                            (txtPortEingabe.getLength() >= 1)) {
                        btnClient.setDisable(false);
                    }
                    //else disable
                    else {
                        btnClient.setDisable(true);
                    }
                    //If the input of Port is done and Ip input empty enable 
                    //Button Server
                    if(txtPortEingabe.getLength() >= 1 && txtIPEingabe.getLength() == 0) {
                        btnServer.setDisable(false);
                    }
                    //else disable
                    else {
                        btnServer.setDisable(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    Thread t1 = new Thread(checkChangeSettings);
    t1.setDaemon(true);
    t1.start();
    }
```

---

**Solved I used for both Textfields a Listener**

```
txtIPEingabe.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> arg0, 
            String arg1, String arg2) { if requests.......  
            }
       });
```

I am still interest why it did react strange as I used the thread?
Do I have to synchronize the thread by CountDownLatch?

Comment: Yes, click the `edit` link under the tags (or click here [edit])

Comment: I edited it i hope the problem is understandable.

Comment: The question is understandable now.  However, the approach is incorrect.  Not posting as an answer as my UI knowledge is limited. You are polling the fields in a hard loop with no wait, wasting an entire CPU core.  What you should be doing is processing only when a change occurs in either of the two fields.  On each change, and ONLY on a change, test the conditions and enable/disable the buttons.  Unfortunately I don't have time right now to look up the proper API calls, someone else with more UI knowledge can probably help.

Comment: "does not work" isn't a helpful problem description...